# What does exactly mean 'to plant oneself somewhere'?

Tags: word-meaning

What does exactly mean 'to plant oneself somewhere'?

On [MacMillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/plant_2#:%7E:text=to%20firmly%20put%20someone%20or,the%20seat%20next%20to%20me.) we read:

*to firmly put someone or something or yourself in a particular place or position.
Plant something in/on etc something*:

> "Henry planted himself in the seat next to me."

But what emotion does this action convey specifically? What could be the reason for Henry to *plant*—rather than just *seat*—himself in the seat? Does the word, in this case, suggest that Henry was tired, angry, or that he wanted to make sure that no one else would steal that seat?

Comment: I have no idea what emotion might be conveyed, but the *motive* suggested is that Henry has no intention of moving soon.

Comment: Yes, it conveys the sense of making oneself comfortable, generally conveying the impression of having a right to be there.

Comment: To me, "Henry planted himself" implies a very intentional act, but it does not imply anything about Henry's emotions.

Comment: I think although *He planted himself next to me* doesn't really carry any implications about ***his*** emotions, it would nearly always imply that ***I*** would rather he sat somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, "Henry *planted* himself in the seat" carries the connotation that he is firmly sat and has no intention of giving up his seat any time soon. Depending on the context, it may be inferred by extension that Henry is not welcome.

Here are some dictionary examples:

> *She was determined to keep both feet firmly planted on dry land.* (Oxford)
> *She planted her feet firmly to the spot and refused to move.* (Longman)